# npm-install command not working

Tags: npm, npm-install

i am new to nodejs. i was trying to install nodejs as per documentation. while using npm install command to install dependencies, i faced an error.

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! package.json ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Program Files\
nodejs\package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directo
ry.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log

C:\Program Files\nodejs>
```

after running npm install command in folder where package.json file is present it gives this error:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! package.json ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Program Files\
nodejs\package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directo
ry.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log

C:\Program Files\nodejs>
```

[link for npm-debug log file..](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwTgYzZKuzAZOVU4Ujd4WE9KSkk)
any help would be appreciated..
thanks..

Answer (score 2):

to install dependencies node looks for a file in the root of the project called `package.json`, where you have the list of all the dependencies needed for the project. its content looks like [something like this](https://github.com/vlrprbttst/living-styleguide-boilerplate/blob/master/patternlab/package.json):

sounds like you are missing `package.json` in the root of your project.

to install a dependency you usually run a command like

```
npm install NAMEOFTHEDEPENDENCY --save-dev
```

where NAMEOFTHEDEPENDENCY could be `grunt-contrib-sass` for example

this also automatically updates your `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

After installing nodejs try closing your code editor, reopen and run npm install in the same directory as package.json file, forgot to mention, did you install nodejs from https://nodejs.org/en/download/?, thats the first part.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `npm install` to work, you need to be in the same directory as your package.json file. `npm install` then looks at the package.json and installs all the dependancies there.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally

Answer (score 0):

You are running npm install in nodejs folder, you should run it in the project folder. Just make sure npm is in your path.

Comment: after running npm install command in folder where package.json file is present it gives this error:

Answer (score 0):

Start with

```
npm init
```

this will create package.json file (you will be asked for some data to fill it).
Then `npm intall <package> [--save|saveDev]` will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I was running the command in a wrong file path, just returned to the correct path and everything went alright

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error when trying to implement the things that are demonstrated in the "***Techworld with Nana***" course, Then install Node.js for windows first and then try the "npm install" command in the Visual studio code terminal.

PS: Make sure you restart the visual studio code application once Node.js for windows is installed.

Answer (score 0):

npm install is throwing error
then you can use
npm audit fix --force(this will update all the dependencies)
then you can use
npm start
You can now view keeper-app-part-1-starting in the browser.

Local:            http://localhost:3000
On Your Network:  http://10.5.174.166:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully